# Substract from SCSS variable value?

Tags: css, sass

I have a SCSS mixin like so:

```
@for $i from 2 through 4 {
  &__layout:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    transition: transform 0.4s ease #{$i}s;
  }
}
```

How can I subtract something from `#{$1}s`? For example, this works:

```
transition: transform 0.4s ease #{$i+1}s;  // <-- adds 1 to value as expected
```

But this gives an error:

```
transition: transform 0.4s ease #{$i-1}s;  // Undefined variable: "$i-1".
```

So I assume this is because variables can have dashes in them? So how do I escape the minus sign so I can subtract from the variable?

Comment: try adding a space between the variable and the operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes just give the space it works

```
@for $i from 2 through 4 {
  &__layout:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    transition: transform 0.4s ease #{$i - 1}s;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks I didn't know the spacing made a difference. Looking more closely at documentation I can see it does though. Thanks,

Comment: Sure thing. Sorry there is a 15 minute window were you can't accept answer after submitting post.